# How to determine total processor time for a process in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am using the `Process.TotalProcessorTime` command to get the total process time for that process. But it doesn't work properly for the same process when it runs multiple times. Can anyone provide the proper solution or suggest a new method in C#?

Comment: "doesn't work properly", do you have an example of what you see versus what you expected?

Comment: It reminds me of a joke: "People don't seem tell me the time correctly -- every time I ask a different person, I get a different answer."

Answer (score 0):

If you run an *application* multiple times, they are all different *processes*. Are you trying to record the total time for an application? You'd need to monitor the system constantly and check when the process runs, not easy. Or you can implement this timing mechanism in the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can attach the process to perfmon,add Performance counters and get the processor time for the process.

Comment: would you please tell an example of using performence counter to get the process time

Comment: open perfmon and click on add counters. Under "available counters" select processor time. In the "Instances of the Selected object" select thr process and then start the counter.This can be automated as well. But if you want include it in your C# app i am not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach is to use

// Get all instances of "myprocess" actually running on the local computer.

```
Process[] LocProcByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("myprocess");
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into the % Processor time performance counter for the process. Details can be found in - http://pandeysk.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/performance-measurement-in-net/